# What is the meaning of "by time"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-request

Is it correct to say, the profits show improvement by time

Does it mean here that profits increase year after year?

Comment: "Is it correct to say, the profits show improvement by time?" Nope.

Comment: how can I say that? by the years maybe?

Comment: 'Profits have increased year on year since 2010'.

Comment: the index scores show a dramatic improvement year on year?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: "Over time" or "over a period of n years"

Comment: "Year on year" is not correct. "From year to year" would do.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast "Year on year" has in fact become fairly widely used in financial circles in the narrow context of comparing current data to those of one year earlier.

Comment: @StoneyB - I stand corrected. My apologies.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Eh, it's financial jargon; not something people should be expected to know.

Comment: He could just say: "Profits showed improvement with time." This keeps his original sentence intact. However, his first sentence and the second one definitely do not mean the same thing. Also it is "year-over-year". You need the hyphens. (I am a financial analyst.) It is not "jargon", but actual terminology that denotes a process and amalgamates several concepts that are not reducible to something else. It is no more jargon than "compound' is in science. Ben Kim, if you still need a full answer, I can draft one for you. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> The profits show improvement by time

This means, as time moves forward, profits improve.

The sentence above is not specific as to the interval of the time.  You can say any of:

> The profits show yearly improvement by time.
>
> The profits show improvement yearly by time.
>
> The profits show improvement by time yearly.

but then "by time" is redundant (because both "by time" and "yearly" modify "improvement" and "yearly" is already a time expression) and doesn't need to be in the sentence, unless you are emphasizing that there is an improvement by time rather than some other metric, such as by customer, etc.

If you say:

> The yearly profits show improvement by time.

you are saying a set of yearly profits are steadily improving over a number of years.  This is not redundant as "yearly" is qualifying "profits", not "improvement."

Answer (score 0):

As for the specific question being asked, you would be much more likely to encounter "profits show improvement over time", or some other variation using "over" (at least in US usage, I suppose elsewhere may differ).